# How does x265 calculate bitrate?

Tags: video-encoding, hevc, libx265

I'm using x265 to encode a video. A get the bitrate summary and bitrate for each group of encoding frames.

When I calculate the average bitrate of the groups it does not converge with the summary bitrate.

Any ideas about how x265 calculates summary bitrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

It's the division of the average of the given Bits values per GOP with (1000 (for kb) multiply by the time length for the GOP).

For example `GOP = 96`, `FPS = 30Hz`, thus `time length = 96/30 = 3.2`

So, `summary bitrate (per GOP) = (average bits)/(1000*3.2)` valued in kbps